# simple in and out animation with android

Tags: java, android, android-animation

i have some questions to the animations on android:

first of all, does someone have good links to sites where animations for android get explained? Only XML-Animations please, i dont want to use java-code for the animations..

The second question: I want to simply animate the activity from tight to left when it comes up and from left to right when it goes, but i can't achieve this simple animation.

My XML Files look like this:

```
 push left in:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
push right out:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="100%p" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

In my code i use: `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in,R.anim.push_right_out);` and `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_right_out,R.anim.push_left_in);` after the `super.finiah();`

Comment: are you calling overridePendingTransition() before or after you call startActivity(Intent)?

Comment: i am calling it after this function

Comment: check my answer, maybe separate your animation files and substitute your code into what I've shown

Answer (score 2):

This is how I set up a simple fade in, fade out animation

Here's my incoming.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" >

<alpha
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

Here's my outgoing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" >

<alpha
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

And here's how I call set the animation in my activity

```
 Intent i = new Intent(this, ABCActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                ModeSelectActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(
                    R.anim.outgoing, R.anim.incoming);
```

Also, be sure to override onBackPressed() for the reverse animation

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();

    ModeSelectActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.outgoing,
            R.anim.incoming);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many animations on this page:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.5_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/anim/

You can look at slide_in_left.xml,slide_in_right.xml, slide_out_left.xml and slide_out_right.xml.

You can use these transitions with overridePendingTransition().